# Settlers of Catan: does the "knight card steal" have to be random?

Tags: catan

When using a knight card, can you negotiate with your opponent to agree on a specific resource card that may be mutually beneficial?

For example, let's say I desperately need a sheep and use a knight card (or roll a 7). My opponent has one or multiple sheep cards they don't particularly need. However, they have a brick they really need for something else and woudn't want to have it stolen. Can both players agree to handing over a sheep?

Comment: Oops didn't notice the duplicate before.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The steal itself must be random, but you can easily "fix" this by doing a trade afterwards.

From [the rules](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/7a/18/fd-catan-rulebook.pdf):

> (2) Then you steal 1 (random) resource card from an
> opponent who has a settlement or city adjacent to the target
> terrain hex. **The player who is robbed holds his resource
> card hand face down. You then take 1 card at random.**

If you end up stealing a brick, then you and your opponent can now simply agree to trade that brick for a sheep; and you both end up with what you want. It's the same end result; but you have the ability to decide whether or not to make that trade only after seeing what you steal. It also gives you more information; if you had stolen a sheep right away you may have not known or remembered if your opponent had any brick.

Comment: It follows that one can make it a house rule allowing to ask for voluntarily giving up a sheep without violating the intent of the official rule. The asker would then voluntarily forfeit the extra information mentioned in the answer and tell the whole table what resource exactly they need, but it would improve the playing speed.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that when you shuffle and fan your cards, for one to be taken at random, then it would be legal to say my sheep is on the right hand side.

The other player would obviously have to trust you and this trust would be based off the previous conversation about who wanted to gain/lose what.

Comment: Interesting idea!

Comment: Some house rules might require that the player shuffle their hand face-down so that even they don't know what cards are where before the steal, which would defeat that strategy.

Comment: This seems like spurious semantics. If you tell the opponent something about your hand to make the steal not random, then the opponent would have to resort to a die or something to follow the rule: "take 1 card at random".